# how to convert a uint32 variable to 2 unit 16 variables?

Tags: c++, vector, type-conversion

I have a vector of uint32 variables that has no meaning for me . but first 16 bits and second 16 bits of them have meaning . Then i need to separate it indexes to 2 uint16 variables in c++ .
what should i do for this issue ?

Comment: `uint16_t first = your_number, second = your_number >> 16;`.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an implementation.

```
vector<uint32_t> a = {/*your data goes here*/};
vector<uint16_t> mostSignificantBits, leastSignificantBits;
for(uint32_t i : a) {
    mostSignificantBits.push_back((uint16_t)(i >> 16));
    leastSignificantBits.push_back((uint16_t)i);
}
```

Simply casting it will take the 16 least significant bits.

To retrieve the most significant bits, we use right shift.